# ML create word2vec from scratch

Tags: machine-learning, word2vec

I am trying to write a simple version of word2vec from scratch. Main reason is I need to make changes in the algorithm to get n-gram not just a single word per context input. Does anyone know where I can find the algorithm for word2vec skip-gram model? I write my code in java.

- I download and handle the corpus.
- I created all methods for calculation.

My aim is to use negative sampling with sigmoaid

Comment: It's in the Mikolov et al. paper from 2013. In general, questions that ask for help finding an external resource aren't an appropriate fit for Stack Overflow.